# Is there any justifiable value in multi-level/tree selectors when using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Aside from keeping some kind of structured mark-up, is there any justifiable reason to use multi-level/tree selectors when it comes to CSS or jQuery.

**What I mean by multi-level/tree selectors:**

`$('#grand-parent > #parent > .child').doSomething();`

`#grand-parent #parent .child`

I often see people using this type of selection, even though there's no other element in the DOM with the class of `.child`, hence why I'm wondering whether there is a need for it/reason behind using it in scenario's where the end selector (`.child`) only exists once?

So that this isn't subjective, and is a question that can have a genuine answer; when I say need or reason, I mean something like performance boosts, or errors that can occur when elements aren't selected in this fashion.

Also, as a side question, is there any need for the `>` greater than sign in a jQuery selection, as I'm pretty sure I've seen CSS with and without it.

Any answers/explanations as to the use of multi-level selectors would be greatly appreciated ;).

Good day everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the > sign as i have made selectors without it like #MyID.Myclass without any issue. As for performance if you don't have to iterate through everything in the DOM to get at your controls this is optimal however if what you are going after is just a class there is no reason to filter it out. Also the other poster is correct about creating brittle code. Processing power on the local client does the heavy lifting so spening an extra milisecond to grab the data is not a problem compared to the possible programming errors and complexity that could arise.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful sometimes when the selectors involve nestable elements:

```
$('dl.main-list > dt').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

That way any nested `<dl>` lists don't get messed up.

In general however making assumptions about document structure outside of things like my example are, in my opinion, pretty fragile.

Comment: Yeah, I could understand the use where you're selecting HTML elements of which there are multiple within the same nest, or multiple nests, e.g. `ul > li`. However, in the case of user defined classes being the select point for the most parent (in my particular coding style), and a low reliance on lists and other default nested elements, I'm thinking the best approach for me, is to select as close too the node as possible, and then traverse up the tree as/if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always confused by people who stridently advocate "seperating markup from script", then use complex selectors to access elements based on the layout. It makes some sense from a styling viewpoint to use complex selectors, but even then the more complex they are, the harder it is to maintain.